# When I Change the IIS Application Pool Identity User Use Custom Account it stops the Application pool even if I start it again

Tags: c#, windows, .net-core, iis

When I Change the IIS Application Pool Identity User.

I am using Custom Account, Domain User.

It stops the Application pool even if I start it again.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What user/account value did you select for the Custom Account field?

Comment: Not all users can be used as pool identity, as IIS mandates quite a few user rights, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/www-authentication-authorization/default-permissions-user-rights#default-windows-user-rights-assignments You usually need to work with your domain administrators to learn which are the suitable accounts to use.

Comment: @Dai This account is a Domain account not matter the name

Answer (score -2, accepted):

first, this issue is because the application pool cant log in with the user u give to it.

as a **workaround** and **temporary** **Solution**:

1- go to ComputerManagement from the start menu.

2- open Local Users and Groups.

3- open Administrator Group

4- add your user to this group.

5- start your application pool again

[image]
it should work

Comment: This is **very bad advice** so I downvoted it. There is absolutely no reason to escalate `w3wp`'s permissions like this - especially as IIS is publicly exposed: it's important that all service-principals are running with least-privilege, but this answer basically suggests running application-code as `root` - **bad**.

Comment: So what is the best solution if this advice is too bad and this is as a workaround Solution